# Foreach loops Always runs the last object results

Tags: powershell

I'm still new with the powershell, there's a questions with my script, my intention is to import the CSV data under column Name
then do a split() for each object with "computername" and "username", however it can catch the arrays with two results, but after the loop in Foreach it only runs the last object. Can someone help Thanks!

whole code

```
$ImportPath ="C:\data.csv"
$ComputerArray= @()

Import-Csv -Path $ImportPath |ForEach-Object{$ComputerArray+= $_.Name}

Foreach($Hostname in $ComputerArray){
$CharArray =$Hostname.Split("\")
$ComputerName = $CharArray[0]
$Username = $CharArray[1] 

}
```

CSV date looks like
[CSV data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNvHm.png)

```
$ComputerArray results
----------------------
Computer1\Local User
Computer2\Remote User
```

Hopes to look like

```
$ComputerName results
---------------------
Computer1
Computer2

$Username results
---------------------
Local User
Remote User
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not running the last object only, it's running all the objects but you're only capturing the last one. Both variables `$computerName` and `$userName` are getting re-assigned on each iteration.

Below will give you an array of objects with the `Computer` and `User` properties for each line of your CSV.

```
$ImportPath = "C:\data.csv"
$ComputerArray = (Import-Csv -Path $ImportPath).Name

$result = foreach($Hostname in $ComputerArray)
{
    $ComputerName, $Username = $Hostname.Split("\")
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Computer = $ComputerName
        User = $Username
    }
}

$result | Format-Table
```

If you want to get the computers on one array and the users on other array like in your expected output you can do `$result.Computer` and `$result.User`.

Comment: Hi Squarzon,

Thanks a lot for your promptly reply! It works!